# POST body not sending through cURL using JSON

Tags: node.js, json

I am trying to use Postman to send POST messages to my application.  When sending the POST message, I receive an HTTP 200 code.  In the response, I only get my incremented id, and not the JSON object I send.

When I try to use cURL from the CMD prompt, I get an error.

I am using Node and Express for my application

Here is my application and POST method

```
const express = require('express');
const Joi = require('joi');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json({extended: false}));

// POST

app.post('/api/courses', (req, res) => {

   const {error} = validateCourse(req.body);

   if(error){
      return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
   }
   const course = {
      id: (courses.length + 1),
      name: req.params.name
   };

   courses.push(course);
   res.send(course);
});

// validateCourse method

function validateCourse(course){
   const schema = {
      name: Joi.string().min(3).required()
   };
   return Joi.validate(course, schema);
}
```

Postman
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBIDt.png)

POST headers
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jyl3M.png)

Application after several POST messages

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdwRo.png)

Comment: If it works with postman and not with curl, you need to at least share the curl statement you're using to test this.

Comment: it works with neither

Comment: that was it... Thanks phil!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is that your route accepts no [route parameters](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters) but you are trying to use `req.params.name`.

Your data is in `req.body`

```js
const course = {
  ...req.body,
  id: courses.length + 1
};
```

To send the equivalent request with curl, use this

```sh
curl \
  -H "content-type: application/json" \
  -d '{"name":"abcde"}' \
  "http://localhost:3000/api/courses"
```

FYI, the [express.json()](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json) middleware doesn't have an `extended` option

```js
app.use(express.json());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
   const course = {
      id: (courses.length + 1),
      name: req.body.name
   };
```